# Using custom Search Properties in PNP Search SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp

I have a list with some values, which I need to be searchable. One field is a lookup field, which shows the status of a project. The values are stored in another list (running, on hold and completed). How I can map the field in my main list "Projects" field name (lookup field) "Status" to a RefinableString00 e.g.

I did this before, but it shows only the value: Null

How can this achived that I can use it in my PNP Search Templates?

Thanks in advance!

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

How did you map "Status" to RefinableString00?

I operate it on my server:

[image]

As a result, I could search for it on my PnP search box, just notice here I search for RefinableString00:red instead of RefinableString00. If we do not add the value of the column, we will not get the search result we want.

[image]

Comment: But it's a little hard to get used to the user

Comment: You mean we need to search for RefinableString00:red is hard to get used? For now, if we do not add the column value to managed property, we will get no result in search box.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to connect the managed properties to the crawled propterties. Then I wait and voila, I have all the values I needed.

This is also working for lookup fields.

Best regards

Matthias